# Gradle Build - Timeout waiting to lock journal cache

Tags: gradle

Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (/Users/username/.gradle/caches/journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When I run the command `./gradlew build or run` I got this response: `                        `> Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (/Users/user/.gradle/caches/journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.                         Owner PID: 38270
                             Our PID: 39060
                             Owner Operation: 
                             Our operation: 
                             Lock file: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/journal-1/journal-1.lock`

Comment: I have the same issue. It is crucial problem

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, search all processes associated to gradle with "`ps -fea | grep gradle`" and then kill all of them with "`kill -9 PROC_IDs`"

Comment: This process was used by the IdeaUltimate (in my case). And this only stops it. However, I suppose it will be repeated in future.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to kill the process with the ID provided in the error message as Owner PID:

```
kill -9 [OwnerPID]
```